# Getting options by value from select element in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, html-select

I want to access the select option jQuery objects as such:

```
var $options = $('select').children();
var $someOption = $('[value="some_value"]', $options);
var $anotherOption = $('[value="another_value"]', $options);
```

but neither `$someOption` or `$anotherOption` look like any of the elements in `$('select')`.

I believe I know how to compose the one line selector but since I'm accessing various options, I wanted to use the `$options` handle for readability and performance instead.

What is wrong with the code and/or rationale?

Comment: Did you accidentally exclude the `$` from the selectors for `$someOption` and `$anotherOption`?

Comment: You seem to be missing the `$` for the jQuery function on your second and third selectors.

Comment: @ExplosionPills, jmoerdyk, thank you, I now fixed the OP typos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use jQuery's [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method:

```
var $options = $('select').children();
var $someOption = $options.filter('[value="some_value"]');
var $anotherOption = $options.filter('[value="another_value"]');
```

Comment: Passing in a jQuery object as the second parameter acts as the context to select from, so it does the same thing as your code EDITED (this statment is incorrected)

Comment: @JustinBicknell - Nope. Passing in a context searches for descendants, and [is equivalent to this](http://jsfiddle.net/P8QAj/): `$options.find('[value="some_value"]')`

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the context parameter, don't call `.children()`.

```
var $select = $('select');
var $someOption = $('[value="some_value"]', $select);
var $anotherOption = $('[value="another_value"]', $select);
```

Comment: This'll traverse the DOM each time. Filtering only looks at the set being filtered.

Comment: @JosephSilber True, although it only has to traverse the subset of the DOM below the select, not the entire DOM, so it's not too bad.

Comment: True, but what benefit does it offer over filtering?

Comment: @JosephSilber It's less verbose, some may find it more readable, which is one of the criteria the OP is looking for.